# Exclude index in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple requirement of removing couple of lines in a file. I found little help on the net , where we can make use of Index. Suppose i want to select 5th line i use

```
Get-Content file.txt | Select -Index 4
```

Similarly, what if i dont need the 5th and 6th line? How would the statement change?

```
Get-Content file.txt | Select -Index -ne 4
```

I tried using -ne between -Index and the number. It did not work. neither did "!=".

Also the below code gives no error but not the desired output

```
$tmp = $test  |   where {$_.Index -ne 4,5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the `Index` property or parameter, but you can also achieve it like this :

```
$count = 0
$exclude = 4, 5
Get-Content "G:\input\sqlite.txt" | % {
    if($exclude -notcontains $count){ $_ }
    $count++
}
```

**EDIT :**

The `ReadCount` property holds the information you need :)

```
$exclude = 0, 1
Get-Content "G:\input\sqlite.txt" | Where-Object { $_.ReadCount -NotIn $exclude }
```

WARNING : as pointed by @PetSerAl and @Matt, *`ReadCount` starts at 1 and not 0 like arrays*

Comment: Thanks, I have added a warning

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline elements does not have `Index` auto-property, but you can add it, if you wish:

```
function Add-Index {
    begin {
        $i=-1
    }
    process {
        Add-Member Index (++$i) -InputObject $_ -PassThru
    }
}
```

Then you can apply filtering by `Index`:

```
Get-Content file.txt | Add-Index | Where-Object Index -notin 4,5
```

Comment: Pipeline elements don't but return from Get-Content does: `ReadCount`

Comment: @Matt `ReadCount` is valid solution, but it is not zero-based, as indexes normally in PowerShell, so you have to take that into account.

Comment: Of course... I wrote that in an answer until I re-read sodawillow

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get-content file.txt | select -index (0..3 + 5..10000)
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it works.  Downside is that building the range takes some time.  Also, adjust the 10000 to make sure you get the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Convert this as an array and use **RemoveRange** method(ind index, int count)

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$text  = gc C:\file.txt
$text.RemoveRange(4,1)
$text
```